# How to get sum of values grouped by the pandas DataFrame and make numpy matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `pandas DataFrame` initially sorted by the `timestamp` and later grouped by the `ids`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df1 = df.sort_values(['timestamp'],ascending=False).groupby('id')

for d in df1:
    print d
```

When I print the values, I get the following results,

```
('e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02',     feature_a  feature_b                                    id  \
44         93   0.477655  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02   
34         45   0.298734  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02   
96         70   0.425690  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02   
72         29   0.361818  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02   
79          8   0.450535  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02   
21         28   0.307216  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02   
1          44   0.466247  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02   
57         78   0.427387  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02   
26         47   0.301680  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02   
11         18   0.679684  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02   

             timestamp  
44 2016-01-25 14:54:03  
34 2016-01-25 10:23:09  
96 2016-01-23 18:42:29  
72 2016-01-23 03:56:39  
79 2016-01-22 21:42:59  
21 2016-01-13 03:57:52  
1  2016-01-12 16:54:17  
57 2016-01-09 02:14:17  
26 2016-01-06 09:00:02  
11 2016-01-06 03:21:49  )


('faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07',     feature_a  feature_b                                    id  \
50         19   0.070325  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   
66         22   0.463263  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   
19         79   0.494183  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   
16          0   0.473266  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   
17         41   0.887249  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   
65         93   0.923212  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   
29         61   0.813511  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   
90         40   0.021611  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   
84         95   0.125271  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   
43         27   0.128413  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   
38         57   0.209639  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07   

             timestamp  
50 2016-01-29 13:47:32  
66 2016-01-29 00:38:37  
19 2016-01-29 00:20:19  
16 2016-01-24 07:36:08  
17 2016-01-18 05:55:53  
65 2016-01-17 23:10:19  
29 2016-01-14 15:49:25  
90 2016-01-13 09:13:39  
84 2016-01-11 19:33:28  
43 2016-01-09 13:36:54  
38 2016-01-07 22:31:14  )
```

I have interval variable, `SUM_INTERVALS = [(-7,0), (-14,0), (-30,0)]` when means previous 7, 14 and 30 days from the `'2016-02-01'`. For each `ids`, I need to sum up the values of `feature_a` and `feature_b` for the last 7, 14 and 30  and make a `2 x 7` numpy matrix. For reference, 7 columns would composed of

```
id, feature_a_last7, feature_b_last7, feature_a_last14, feature_b_last14, feature_a_last30, feature_b_last30
```

How to solve the problem properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, what you are looking for is something like

```
def sum_period(n_days):
    dfs = df[df.timestamp > pd.to_datetime('2016-02-01') - pd.to_timedelta(n_days, 'D')].groupby('id').sum()
    dfs.columns = ['feature_a_last%d' % n_days, 'feature_b_last%d' % n_days]
    return dfs
pd.concat([sum_period(7), sum_period(14), sum_period(30)], axis=1)
```

Trying this out:

```
In [5]: n =  100  # Let us create 100 points in a dummy DataFrame
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.choice(['e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02', 'faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07'], n),
   ...:                    'feature_a': np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
   ...:                    'feature_b': np.random.uniform(0, 1, n),
   ...:                    'timestamp': pd.to_datetime('2016-02-01') - pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 31, n), 'D')})
   ...:

In [6]: df.head()
Out[6]: 
   feature_a  feature_b                                    id  timestamp
0         85   0.265086  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07 2016-01-18
1         98   0.233029  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07 2016-01-29
2         44   0.188515  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02 2016-01-11
3         33   0.253477  e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02 2016-01-28
4         64   0.308067  faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07 2016-01-08

In [8]: def sum_period(n_days):
   ...:     dfs = df[df.timestamp > pd.to_datetime('2016-02-01') - pd.to_timedelta(n_days, 'D')].groupby('id').sum()
   ...:     dfs.columns = ['feature_a_last%d' % n_days, 'feature_b_last%d' % n_days]
   ...:     return dfs
   ...: pd.concat([sum_period(7), sum_period(14), sum_period(30)], axis=1)
Out[8]: 
                                      feature_a_last7  feature_b_last7  feature_a_last14  feature_b_last14  feature_a_last30  feature_b_last30
id                                                                       
e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02              308         3.493604              1020         11.317915              2515         24.200676
faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07              618         5.068306              1065         10.852343              2041         21.046958
```

Edit regarding constructing an `ndarray` from the data: You will lose the type information if you do so, but you can obtain it through `DataFrame.values` if you first remove the index:

```
    ...: dfs = pd.concat([sum_period(7), sum_period(14), sum_period(30)], axis=1)

In [44]: dfs.reset_index().values
Out[44]: 
array([['e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02', 308, 3.493603705195687,
    1020, 11.317914764942246, 2515, 24.200675542875487],
       ['faed1a76-11ca-452e-8526-ebd0ac7edd07', 618, 5.068306120076799,
    1065, 10.852342937107716, 2041, 21.046958298433765]], dtype=object)

In [45]: dfs.reset_index().values.shape
Out[45]: (2, 7)
```

Comment: This is very helpful and almost correct. However, there is an issue: when I convert it to the `numpy array` using the `pd.as_matrix()`, I get 2 x 6 matrix which suppose to be 2 x7. Obviously, the `id` is missing. How do I incorporate that into the `numpy` array?

Comment: @Are: I don't see how that would work out: numpy `ndarray`s are homogeneous in their data types, but here you are mixing strings, integers, and floats. Now, I don't know the underlying problem you are trying to solve, but chances are that the `DataFrame` is a better data structure for the purpose.

Comment: This is inside a function that would return a `numpy matrix` and I would need to pass some unit tests and hence, the `id`needs to be preceded to the row. How to do that ? Like when you print out the `DataFrame`, I need this to be converted into the `numpy matrix`

Comment: Okay, at least suggest me how to access the `id` values from the `pd.concat` statement.

Comment: You can't: If you try to coerce one of the numerical values into the same `ndarray` as the `id`, it will be turned into a string;

`>>> np.array(['e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02', 308])`

becomes

`array(['e6f78c27-01bb-45c1-b339-b1f74f0f2b02', '308'], dtype='|S36')`. Edit: This was an answer to the first of the two comments.

Comment: The `id` values are part of the index of the concatenation and can be accessed by using `.index`.

Comment: I hope you understand what I need. Can you change the `method` and the `pd.concat` to get the `numpy array` ?

Comment: If you let `df_grouped` be the result of the concatenation, then you can get the numerical values through `df_grouped.values` and the `id` strings through `df_grouped.index`.

Comment: Would you mind to code up little for me ? By the way, I already accepted the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136634/discussion-between-are-and-fuglede).

Answer (score 0):

I would think to create a min date and max date per block.

Then do:

```
df[(df.timestamp>=min_date) & (df.timestamp<=max_date)][my_column].sum()
```

Be sure your date is casted as datetime to avoid unintentional bugs.